# Angularjs delete JSon object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I have little dilemma here. I have a nested json object that is inside ng-repeat and is sortable using [AngularJS UI Sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable) (based on JQuery UI Sortable):

```
$scope.rootItem = {
        id: '1',
        type: 'course',
        title: 'Adobe Photoshop CC for beginners',
        items: [{
            id: '2',
            type: 'label',
            title:'label',
            items:[{
                id: '3',
                type: 'module',
                title:'Module title',
                items: [{
                    id: '4',
                    type: 'topic',
                    title:'Topic title',
                    items: [{
                        id: '5',
                        type: 'content',
                        title:'Content title'
                    }, {
                        id: '6',
                        type: 'content',
                        title:'Content title'
                    }]
                }]
            },{
                id: '7',
                type: 'resources',
                title:'Resources'
            },{
                id: '8',
                type: 'module',
                title:'Module title',
                items: [{
                    id: '9',
                    type: 'topic',
                    title:'Topic',
                    items: [{
                        id: '10',
                        type: 'question',
                        title:'Question title'
                    }]
                }, {
                    id: '11',
                    type: 'topic',
                    title:'Topic title',
                    items: [{
                        id: '12',
                        type: 'content',
                        title:'Content title'
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        },{
            id: '14',
            type: 'assessmentLabel',
            title: 'Assessment Label',
            items: [{
                id: '15',
                type: 'assessment',
                title: 'Assessment Title',
                items: [{
                    id: '16',
                    type: 'courseAssessment',
                    title: 'Course Question Group',
                    items: []
                }]
            }]
        }]
    };
```

What I should be able to do is remove any of the items within this object, and if it has any children they need to be remove too.

So what I would generally think is passing either $index and use splice to remove it (if it was an array).

But for objects doesnt seem to work this way, I read online that delete should be used instead...

On my button I try to pass the object itself as in:

```
data-ng-click="removeItem(ngModelItem)"
```

and in my controller do something like this:

```
// Remove Item from the list
    $scope.removeItem = function(item) {

    };
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You would know in view whether it was parent object or child array item don't you? Need to see how view is structured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ngModelItem`

```
<li ng-repeat="innerItem in ngModelItem.items">
    <a href="#" ng-click="deleteItem(ngModelItem.items, $index)">Delete me</a>
```

in your controller,

```
$scope.deleteItem = function(collection, index){
    collection.splice(index,1);
};
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/davcs86/pen/akjbwr)

Answer (score 0):

For removing json elements from a json object you use the [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete). But in your case, I assume you want to remove a json object from a json array, so you should really use [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) instead.

You should receive both the list and the index in your `removeItem()` function so you can remove the indexed element and angularjs will update your view.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it's just restating what's already in the question in a different way

Comment: The question is literally "Any suggestions?". I gave him a suggestion to keep going on what he intended to do, with more detail and justifications.